# <div> tag to automatically size itself depending on the dynamic table within it

Tags: php, html, css

I have a `<div>` inside a `while` loop and inside this `while` loop I'm dynamically creating `table`s with different number of rows, therefore the `div` tag within the first `while` loop cannot have a pre-set size since some `table`s generated can be longer than expected.

Example of how my code is like:

```
while ()
{
  echo '<div>';
  echo '<table>';
  while ()
  {
     echo '<tr></tr>'; // this varies since  number of row retrieve may be different which is causing the issue
  }
  echo '</table>';
  echo '<div>';
}
```

Comment: it will resize *automatically* if you don't give it a size. It's magic

Comment: I dont get what you are wanting either - height a problem? width a problem? the div will just expand to fit the table so I don't get why you want to give it a size???

Comment: well, give it your size... it's simple: `<div style="width: someSidth; height: some height;">

Comment: You don't state an actual problem, and what you seem to be after is the default. Also, the fact that the markup is generated by PHP isn't relevant here, so it would be better if you included the resulting HTML.

Comment: @Dagon Thanks I can't believe I was wasting so much time on that.....Earlier there was some issue when i left it without a size I thought it was due to the php code being after the div tag.....however now when i removed the style of the div , its appending the second div which is generated by the loop beside the first div. I tried to set the width to 100% so that it'll be below it but its not doing it. :S?

Comment: You're never closing the `div` tag according to your code here!

Comment: opps typo I made sure i closed it @Jon P however the div is appending beside the div before it.

Comment: In which case that div first `div` may not have been close off or has a `float` applied to it. Use a tool like firebug for firefox or developer tools in chrome to inspect your elements in a browser to find out what styles are applied where. Those tools can also help with discovering unclosed or mis-closed tags.